# Using a function and mapply in R to create new columns that sums other columns

Tags: r, function, apply, mapply

Suppose, I have a dataframe, df, and I want to create a new column called "c" based on the addition of two existing columns, "a" and "b". I would simply run the following code:

```
df$c <- df$a + df$b
```

But I also want to do this for many other columns. So why won't my code below work?

```
# Reproducible data:

martial_arts <- data.frame(gym_branch=c("downtown_a", "downtown_b", "uptown", "island"),
                           day_boxing=c(5,30,25,10),day_muaythai=c(34,18,20,30),
                           day_bjj=c(0,0,0,0),day_judo=c(10,0,5,0),
                           evening_boxing=c(50,45,32,40), evening_muaythai=c(50,50,45,50),
                           evening_bjj=c(60,60,55,40), evening_judo=c(25,15,30,0))

# Creating a list of the new column names of the columns that need to be added to the martial_arts dataframe:

pattern<-c("_boxing","_muaythai","_bjj","_judo")
d<- expand.grid(paste0("martial_arts$total",pattern))

# Creating lists of the columns that will be added to each other:

e<- names(martial_arts %>% select(day_boxing:day_judo))
f<- names(martial_arts %>% select(evening_boxing:evening_judo))

# Writing a function and using mapply:

kick_him <- function(d,e,f){d <- rowSums(martial_arts[ , c(e, f)], na.rm=T)}

mapply(kick_him,d,e,f)
```

Now, mapply produces the correct results in terms of the addition:

```
> mapply(ff,d,e,f)
     Var1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
[1,]   55   84   60   35
[2,]   75   68   60   15
[3,]   57   65   55   35
[4,]   50   80   40    0
```

But it doesn't add the new columns to the martial_arts dataframe. The function in theory should do the following

```
martial_arts$total_boxing <- martial_arts$day_boxing + martial_arts$evening_boxing
...
...
martial_arts$total_judo <- martial_arts$day_judo + martial_arts$evening_judo
```

and add four new total columns to martial_arts.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @akrun Sorry, it's supposed to be kick_him.

Comment: The way in which you constructed requires eval/parse etc which is not at all recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment is wrong here i.e. instead of having `martial_arts$total_boxing` as a string, it should be "total_boxing" alone and this should be on the lhs of the `Map/mapply`.  As the OP already created the 'martial_arts$' in 'd' dataset as a column, we are removing the prefix part and do the assignment

```
kick_him <- function(e,f){rowSums(martial_arts[ , c(e, f)], na.rm=TRUE)}
martial_arts[sub(".*\\$", "", d$Var1)] <- Map(kick_him, e, f)
```

-check the dataset now

```
> martial_arts
  gym_branch day_boxing day_muaythai day_bjj day_judo evening_boxing evening_muaythai evening_bjj evening_judo total_boxing total_muaythai total_bjj total_judo
1 downtown_a          5           34       0       10             50               50          60           25           55             84        60         35
2 downtown_b         30           18       0        0             45               50          60           15           75             68        60         15
3     uptown         25           20       0        5             32               45          55           30           57             65        55         35
4     island         10           30       0        0             40               50          40            0           50             80        40          0
```

Comment: Perfect! Although I am not sure what this is ```martial_arts[sub(".*\\$", "", d$Var1)]```. Can you explain this a bit, please.

Comment: @Pineapple it is to remove the `"martial_arts$"` because the column name should be just "day_boxing"

Comment: Okay. So, what if in my "d" list, I only have "total_boxing"? Then how should this ```martial_arts[sub(".*\\$", "", d$Var1)]``` be adjusted?

Comment: @Pineapple then it would be just `martial_arts[d$Var1] <- Map(kick_him, e, f)` assuming the 'Var1' column is `character` class and not `factor`

Comment: When I remove ```martial_arts$``` and do this ```d<- expand.grid(paste0("total",pattern))``` and ```martial_arts[d$Var1] <- Map(kick_him,e,f)```, I get an error:  ```Error in Summary.factor(1:4, na.rm = FALSE) : ‘min’ not meaningful for factors``` Your code in the answer as is works fine.

Comment: Got it! ```martial_arts[as.character(d$Var1)] <- Map(ff,e,f)``` Is this how you'd do it?

Comment: @Pineapple yes, that is correct